# Form File Source a Static URL vs a Different File Upload

Tags: php, excel, forms

I have an excel sheet uploaded to my server (I have the url). Versus sending the file to everyone to then download, upload, and run... I would like to code the button to grab the file url automatically. Is there a way that I can tell it where the source of the file is and then make this a one step process of "submit" and it grabs the file?

```html
<div>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="upload_bulk_order_excel" id="upload_bulk_order_excel" action="bulk_order_summary.php" onsubmit="return check_excel_file();">
    <table width="460">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div>
              <h3><span style="color:rgb(46, 144, 181); text-align:left">Step:</span> Browse
                <input accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" type="file" id="bulk_order_excel_file" name="bulk_order_excel_file" />
              </h3>
              <h3><span style="color:rgb(46, 144, 181); text-align:left">Step:</span> Upload
                <input type="submit" name="form_upload_bulk_order" value="Upload File" style="width: 86px;" />
              </h3>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: No that is not possible, and for very good reasons.  It would then be possible to create a hidden form with a pre-populated path to any file an attacker wanted to grab, and auto-submit the form on page load.